How was the generators $a,b$ of $S_3$ represented in the irreducible representations $1$, $X$, $Y$?
The $S_3$ had two generators
$[a]=[\mathbb{Z}_3]$ and $[b]=[\mathbb{Z}_2]$ with the identity element $e$
It had three irreducible representation.
The first was the one dimensional $trival$ representation $1$, which sent every element to $1$.
The second was the $1$ dimensional "sign" representation $X$.
The third was the $2$ dimensional representation $Y$.
However, I'm a bit confused of how $a$ and $b$ played in the $X$ and $Y$.
For example, in $X$. The elements in $G$, $a\sim \mathbb{Z}_{3}$ and $b\sim \mathbb{Z}_{2}$.
If $a$ and $b$ were both sent to $-1$, then the identity $a^2=(-1)^2 =1$, this clearly is in contradiction to the fact that $a^2\neq e$ in the group representation, i.e. $a^2=1$, $a^3=e=1\neq -1 = a \cdot a^2$.
The two dimensional matrix representation might be represented by the rotation matrix in $\alpha$ plane to be $a=2\pi/3,b=\pi$. But I was told that it was not trivial.
How was the generators $a,b$ of $S_3$ represented in the irreducible representations $1$, $X$, $Y$?

You completely described how these three representations act on $a,b$, so what is your question?

@AnneBauval But in the case of $X$ there's obviously a contradiction, as described.

You proved by contradiction that $X(a)\ne-1$. So, $X(a)=1$.
